# Python 3: "Expected an indent Block" in a comment

Tags: python, compiler-errors

I am new here and German (so English is not so good).

I have written a function in Python and at the top I want to have a comment. The problem is, that Python says "Expected an indent Block" error in the comment.

```
def MakeOneFeedScript():
    z = 1
    CFeedList = [str("null")]*3 #Liste mit Länge der Feeds Erstellen
    #Listen Für 1. 2. 3. Post, usw,
    IFeedList = [] #Liste für Posttime des 1. posts pro feed
    IIFeedList = [] #Liste für Posttime des 2. posts pro feed
    IIIFeedList = [] #Liste für Posttime des 3. posts pro feed
    IVFeedList = [] #Liste für Posttime des 4. posts pro feed
    VFeedList = [] #Liste für Posttime des 5. posts pro feed
    VIFeedList = [] #Liste für Posttime des 6. posts pro feed
    for i in range(z): #Alle Daten aus Dateien Lesen
        s = "/usr/lib/Advanced-Feed/tmp/" + str(i)  #SpeicherortSpeichern
        f = open(s, "rb") #Öffnen
```

Comment: Your indentation is entirely incorrect; please post your actual code, select it all, then use the `{}` (code formatting) button on the toolbar to make sure it is correctly formatted. The `Speicherort Speichern` line is invalid syntax (not part of a comment), the next line is indented too far.

Comment: I can see multiple indentation problems in the code you've posted - the function body isn't indented, and neither is `Speicherort Speichern`. Python `#` comments aren't multi-line.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! After `def MakeOneFeedScript():` you should have indented code. Please check the formatting of the SO post to make sure it's accurate to your script.

Comment: You should read http://www.python-course.eu/python3_blocks.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All dependent lines must be indented:

```
def MakeOneFeedScript():
    z = 1
    CFeedList = [str("null")]*3 #Liste mit Länge der Feeds Erstellen
    # Listen Für 1. 2. 3. Post, usw,
    IFeedList = [] #Liste für Posttime des 1. posts pro feed
    IIFeedList = [] #Liste für Posttime des 2. posts pro feed
    IIIFeedList = [] #Liste für Posttime des 3. posts pro feed
    IVFeedList = [] #Liste für Posttime des 4. posts pro feed
    VFeedList = [] #Liste für Posttime des 5. posts pro feed
    VIFeedList = [] #Liste für Posttime des 6. posts pro feed
    for i in range(z): #Alle Daten aus Dateien Lesen
        s = "/usr/lib/Advanced-Feed/tmp/" + str(i)  #
```

The indentation level is important!

If `Speicherort Speichern` is a comment, it must be preceded by a comment character:

```
# Speicherort Speichern
f = open(s, "rb") #Öffnen
```

If those are part of the previous code, ....

```
    for i in range(z): #Alle Daten aus Dateien Lesen
        s = "/usr/lib/Advanced-Feed/tmp/" + str(i)  #

        # Speicherort Speichern
        f = open(s, "rb") #Öffnen
        ...
        (presumably do something with "f")
```

Comment: So why would you only open the *last* `s` filename? Presumably the `open()` call is part of the `for` loop there.

Comment: @MartijnPieters:   Equally perplexing is why anyone would open the file and not read from it.

Comment: Presumably this is a snippet.